# Firefox popup wont receive cookie

Tags: php, javascript, html, firefox, popup

I'm linking to another page that is opening in a window.

here is the link:

```
<a href='#' onclick=\"window.open('linkadress.php here."','targetWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=200,height=200')\" />
```

Now when i open the file, i want it to be showed to people that are logged in, which is where i encounter my problem..
I'm including my files to the login script, and using both session_start(); and ob_start(); on the page opened in the window, but it just wont use my cookies in there..

Does anyone know why this is happening?

*Update:*
I set my cookies like this:

```
setcookie("cookiename", $value, time()+600);
```

Master is test.com/test/index.php 
popup is test.com/test/pages/popup.php

***Update*** I found out that it works perfectly in IE, but not in Firefox.. Does anyone know what i can do to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are setting cookies in some subdirectory, not the root of domain
this should fix your issue:

```
setcookie("cookiename", $value, time()+600, "/");
```